# $stateParams Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[image]When I was load state using ui-serf my css, js angular js file not load they give me error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**  in angular js 1 but in normally means without ui-sref means using states they load my hole html page with css and all file using state.go

**my code is 
module-**

```
var Fishmart = angular.module('Fishmart', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.router', 
'ui.bootstrap', 'LocalStorageModule', 'slickCarousel']);
```

**controller -**

```
Fishmart.controller('productZoomController', ['$scope', 'ApiCall', 
'$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$timeout', 'myStorageService', ' 
$ocLazyLoad',
function ($scope, ApiCall, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $timeout, 
myStorageService, $ocLazyLoad) {

    var Code = $stateParams.ID;
 }]);
```

**my config file is**

```
Fishmart.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', 
'localStorageServiceProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
'$locationProvider',
function ($ocLazyLoadProvider, localStorageServiceProvider, $stateProvider, 
$urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) 
{
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
$stateProvider
    .state('indexbody', {
        url: '/index',
        controller: 'indexBodyController',
        templateUrl: 'angular_views/Index/indexbody.html',
        resolve: {
            loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'Fishmart',
                    files: ['angular_scripts/controllers/indexBodyController.js']
                })
            }
        }
    }).state('menudetails', {
        url: '/menudetails/:ID',
        controller: 'productZoomController',
        templateUrl: 'angular_views/ProductDetails/productzoom.html',

        resolve: {
            loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'Fishmart',
                    files: ['angular_scripts/controllers/productZoomController.js'
                            , 'assets/css/xzoom.css'
                            , 'assets/js/xzoom.js']
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML CODE

```
<a ui-sref="menudetails({ID:data.ProductCode})" href="#" class="btn btn-
outline-primary btn-lg"><span>Order now !</span></a>
```

please tell me whats wrong

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of error stack?

Comment: Check your network panel in the dev tools. One of the requests, supposed to return JavaScript or JSON, is actually returning HTML.

Comment: they give product code json is working fine even without ui-sref working fine load all CSS as well as JS file properly

Comment: @DevangNaghera  i upload error pic please check it out